# How to kill simulator in xcode 11?

Tags: ios, xcode

> killall Simulator

No matching processes belonging to you were found

Its not working for me, i refered the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648225/kill-ios-simulator-from-terminal) but doesn't contain correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually `killall "Simulator"` works for me, just add quotation marks. Or you can check in Activity Monitor how Simulator process is named.

Comment: Its not work for me. Same error "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Answer (score 0):

```
killall "iOS Simulator"
```

is the correct syntax.

Comment: Its not work for me. Same error "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Answer (score 0):

`xcrun simctl shutdown booted` shuts down all running simulators.

https://github.com/twostraws/ControlRoom provides a nice GUI for this and has tons of other options.